# Stateless functions vs classes in React 16 Performance

Tags: performance, reactjs

Do stateless functions in React 16, have, compared to classes still a better performance?

Should we still differentiate between stateless function and classes for performance reasons only?

Comment: stateless functional components do not have acess to shouldComponentUpdate so they are not optimal.

Comment: @Omar Thank you. The question is specific to performance not functionality.

Comment: shouldComponent update improves performance because it can tell a component whether it needs to re render or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see any performance benefits of functional components in React. In fact, if your component is pure, inheriting from `React.PureComponent` gives less re-renders and, because of that, better performance.
You can make functional components behave the same using [pure from recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#pure), so it comes mostly to your preference - functional vs OOP.